# Static content file extensions

Tags: liferay

I'm having trouble loading a xml file from liferay's static content. I'm getting `HTTP 404`. Are the allowed file extensions configured somewhere? Liferay version is 5.2.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific about the static content part? which location and in what manner you are loading the xml file

Comment: I'm adding files through admin control panel. Content -> Static Content -> Add files. Image files work but xml not.